# Find whether column values are contains in list in python

Tags: python-3.x

Find if values in columns contains in list in python

I have one dataframe 'a' and other as list 'b'. I want to find whether 'a' value is present in list 'b' as below. If present print "found" else "not found"

```
a=['BUHARIREST','SAMCO','MCDONALS']
b=['BUHARIRESTAN','BUHARIHOTEL','SAMCOMUL']

a=pd.DataFrame(a)
a['c']=np.NaN
a['c']=a['c'].astype(str)
a.rename(columns={0:'a'},inplace=True)
```

```py
for i,row in a.iterrows():
    if row['a'] in b:
        a.at[i,'c']='Found'
    else:
        a.at[i,'c']='Not Found'
```

With the help of above code i am trying to achieve that, but "in" operators checks exactly the same word from dataframe 'a' is present in the list.

Expected results:

```
       a               c
0   BUHARIREST      Found
1   SAMCO           Found
2   MCDONALS        Not Found
```

Actual results:

```
       a               c
0   BUHARIREST      Not Found
1   SAMCO           Not Found
2   MCDONALS        Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for substring inside `b`, so `in` will not work here, and `find()` method is a better option. Here's a solution you can try, not optimized but will work.

```
# Checking if values in a['a'] are present as substring in b
# Will return a list with values -1 if no match, 0 if match
a['c'] = a['a'].map(lambda x : [s.find(x) for s in b])

# If a match was found and hence value was 0, -ve sum will not
# be equal to length of b
a['c'] = a['c'].map(lambda x : 'FOUND' if -np.sum(x)!=len(b) else 'NOT FOUND')
```

Comment: Thanks @supratim haldar that will work for this scenario, but I am having **Multiple List** like **'b'** and **Multiple Columns** like **'a'**. Say for ex: I am having 4 folumns in dataframe 'a', i need to find if any value from these columns is match with the list 'b' then i will category that one as "FOOD" else i will checking again with these columns with another list 'c', if its present there i will tagging that one as "TRANSPORT". Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do this - create a temporary column `tmp` which will store concatenated string of other 4 columns. Then write a function which will take `a['tmp']` and all lists as input, and check for presence `tmp` in one list after another, and return a result string accordingly. You can then call this function from `Series.map()` as above.